# for+if loop doing me some problems

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, if-statement

I am getting a course name+ grade from an API, trying to build div for each course with grade next to him, this works for me.

I tried to color each grade according to its value:

- above `80` get class name `goodGrade` which have `color: green`
- under `55` is `badGrade` which have `color: red`
- and `55-80`, `medGrade`, colored in yellow.

For some reason, all my grade get class `badGrade` in addition to `goodGrade` or `medGrade`. So right now even grade `98` is colored in red.

```
for(let i=0 ; i<data.length; i++) {
  $(`.courses`).append(`
    <div class="course"><b>${data[i].courseName}:</b>
      <span class="grade">${data[i].examMark}</span>
    </div>
  `) 

  if(data[i].examMark>55) {
    if(data[i].examMark>80) {
      $(`.courses .grade`).addClass(`goodGrade`)
    } else {
      $(`.courses .grade`).addClass(`medGrade`)
    }
  } else {
    $(`.courses .grade`).addClass(`badGrade`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your  "data" object

Comment: Try like this---> if (parseInt(data[i].examMark, 10) > 55)

Comment: try `parseInt(data[i].examMark) > 55`

Comment: This is not a descriptive title. Please change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is all your courses have same class grade. Therefore this js `$('.courses .grade').addClass('goodGrade')`  will be add to elements have `grade` class. You need to mix unique course. 
Something like this

```
for(let i=0 ; i<data.length; i++){
   let course = '<div class="course" id="course_'+ i +'">'
   $('.courses #course_'+ i +' .grade').addClass(`goodGrade`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with your existing code, you can just add the class name to the last element of the array (Since we are appending div's) `$('.courses .course').last()`

```js
let data = [
    {
      courseName: 'English',
     examMark: 55
    }, {
      courseName: 'Hindi',
     examMark: 60
    }, {
      courseName: 'Science',
     examMark: 90
    }
]
for(let i=0 ; i<data.length; i++){
  $(`.courses`).append(`<div class="course"><b>${data[i].courseName}:</b> <span class="grade">${data[i].examMark}</span></div>`);
  let clName = data[i].examMark > 80 ? 'goodGrade' : (data[i].examMark > 55 ? 'medGrade' : 'badGrade');
  $('.courses .course').last().find('.grade').addClass(clName)
}
```

```css
.course .grade.medGrade {
  color: grey;
}

.course .grade.badGrade {
  color: red;
}

.course .grade.goodGrade {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='courses'></div>
```